# Android Firebase Query to find more than one value in different keys

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a search function like facebook that help  all user to search other user by more than one value under Users list in my application.

I read the example from here 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

here is my firebase :
[image: firebase]

I able to search the the user from firebase by "fullname" . here is my application :
[image: my applicantion]

```
usersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    Query searchAllQuery = usersRef
            .orderByChild("fullname")
            .startAt(searchBoxInput.toUpperCase())
            .endAt(searchBoxInput.toLowerCase() + "\uf8ff" )
```

**edited**
this is the code for my recycle view

```
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<SearchUserList> options = 
             new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<SearchUserList>()
            .setQuery(searchAllQuery, SearchUserList.class).build();
```

I expected the output can be search by more that one value for example :

```
.orderByChild("fullname")
.orderByChild("username")
.orderByChild("country")
```

1. when I key in USA , all user with value "usa" will show out.
2. when I search for username "wei" ,users with value "wei" will show in the list

Comment: You mean the output can be filtered by various values?

Comment: @ConstantinBeer yes,  when we search for Fullname / nickname , user with that value will show out. From the example above , i can search TTT / sp to find out this user from my firebase

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. So for example you could have a property `"country_username_fulname": "usa_sp_TT"` For a longer example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase doesn't support ordering by multiple queries.

> Queries can only order by **one key at a time**. Calling orderByChild()
>   multiple times on the same query throws an error.

Try ordering by a simple query an then filter the data, sample:

```
Query searchAllQuery = usersRef
            .orderByChild("fullname")
            .startAt(searchBoxInput.toUpperCase())
            .endAt(searchBoxInput.toLowerCase() + "\uf8ff" )

searchAllQuery.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        // filter your data here by username and country
        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        if (user.getUsername().contains('wei')  || user.getCoutnry().contains('usa')) {
            // add the user to your list maybe?
        }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: So can I assume that this is the best way to create a search function that can search for multiple values ​​in my "user"?

Comment: so i can just add the query code you provide on top of this--> FirebaseRecyclerOptions<SearchUserList>

Comment: you can view my edited line above

Comment: Yes and then in your adapter, filter out the values

Comment: If you don't want the query to run if field is empty, just put a check for empty field.